# php не загружает несколько файлов

Tags: php

Есть вот такой код:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $index => $value) {
    $$index = $value;
}


$uploaddir = './files/';

for ($i=0; $i<=count($_FILES); $i++) {
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir.basename($_FILES['userFile']['name'][$i]);
    if (copy($_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadFile))
    {
    echo "<h3>Файл успешно загружен на сервер</h3>";
    }
    else { echo "<h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</h3>";}
}
?>


<form action="mce.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="userFile[]" type="file" multiple><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

По идее должно загружать много файлов, но больше двух файлов не грузит. Я понимаю, что какая то ошибка в цикле, но что то не могу сообразить как исправить. Что не так?

Comment: Ну а где используется `$_POST` ?

Comment: а как именуете input'ы?

Comment: ошибка не в цикле, а в том, как вы нарисовали html-форму. Покажите её.

Comment: Дописал код формы

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере `count($_FILES)` всегда будет единичкой, так как `$_FILES['userfile']` будет [содержать подмассив](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.multiple.php) информации о нескольких файлах, а не сам `$_FILES`.

Также ошибка в этой строке `$i < count($_FILES['userFile']['name']`, у вас стояло `<=`, но надо ставить просто знак меньше, так как отчет от нуля.

Ну и применяйте move_uploaded_file, по крайней мере по этому пути пошли разработчики.

```
<form action="uploadfiles.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="userFile[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $uploaddir = __DIR__ . '/files/';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['userFile']['name']); $i++) {
        $uploadFile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userFile']['name'][$i]);

        echo $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userFile']['name'][$i]);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadFile)) {
            echo "<h3>Файл успешно загружен на сервер</h3>";
        } else {
            echo "<h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</h3>";
        }
    }
}
```